# In Daniel 7:22 is judgment "committed to" the saints or "rendered in favor of" them?

Tags: greek, 1-corinthians, daniel, eschatology

The KJV seems to suggest that judgment was committed to the saints so that they became the judges:

> KJV Daniel 7:22 Until the Ancient of days came, and **judgment was
>   given to the saints of the most High**; and the time came that the
>   saints possessed the kingdom.

However, it appears that most other English translation see it as a "ruling in the favor of" the saints:

> New International Version until the Ancient of Days came and
>   **pronounced judgment in favor of** the holy people of the Most High, and
>   the time came when they possessed the kingdom.
>
> New Living Translation until the Ancient One--the Most High--came and
>   **judged in favor of** his holy people. Then the time arrived for the holy
>   people to take over the kingdom.
>
> English Standard Version until the Ancient of Days came, and **judgment
>   was given for the saints** of the Most High, and the time came when the
>   saints possessed the kingdom.
>
> New American Standard Bible  until the Ancient of Days came and
>   **judgment was passed in favor of** the saints of the Highest One, and the
>   time arrived when the saints took possession of the kingdom.

I note that even the ESV goes with the idea of "ruled in the favor of".

The Lexham English Septuagint also has "rendered":

> LES This continued until the ancient of days came and **rendered
>   judgment for the saints of the most high**. And the appointed time
>   arrived and the saints possessed the kingdom.

The NET Bible notes have this to say:

> 50 tc In the LXX, Syriac, and Vulgate the verb is active,
>   understanding “judgment” to be the object rather than the subject of
>   the verb (i.e., “the Ancient of Days rendered judgment”). This
>   presupposes a different vocalization of the verb (יְהַב [yéhav] rather
>   than the MT יְהִב [yéhiv]).
>
> Biblical Studies Press. (2006). The NET Bible First Edition Notes (Da
>   7:22). Biblical Studies Press.

Does the KJV get this one wrong?

See related: [In 1 Corinthians 6:2-3 why does Paul seem to expect the Corinthians to know that they will judge angels?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/33165/in-1-corinthians-62-3-why-does-paul-seem-to-expect-the-corinthians-to-know-that)

Comment: As far as the Aramaic, I suspect it has to do with the interpretation of a single *lamed*, "-לְ the saints". Judgement rendered *for* the saints (applied to their case) or *for* the saints (in their favour)? Incidentally, I don't see the KJV as incompatible with either reading.

Comment: Is there any ambiguity as which it is?

Comment: Not sure about the Aramaic nuances. In Hebrew I think it would be ambiguous (taken without context, anyway).

Comment: I agree with Luke Sawczak. If there is ambiguity in the original text then it should be preserved in English, which the KJV has done. A footnote giving the options would be helpful. Regardless of how one interprets verse 22, verse 27 makes it abundantly clear the saints are given dominion of the kingdom: "*And the kingdom and dominion, and the greatness of the kingdom under the whole heaven, shall be given to the people of the saints of the most High*". Dominion, of course, means they get to call the shots, i.e. exercise judgment.

Comment: Well, post it as an answer and we'll see if the Hebrew people shoot it down. If not, we have a winner!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any ambiguity that may be present in Daniel 7:22, can be resolved by considering this: the judgment of the LORD "rendered in favor of" the saints, is that judgment "be committed" to the saints.

This is precisely what Daniel says at the conclusion to the chapter.

> <sup>26</sup>But the judgment shall sit, and they shall take away his dominion, to consume and to destroy it unto the end. <sup>27</sup>And the kingdom and dominion, and the greatness of the kingdom under the whole heaven, shall be given to the people of the saints of the most High, whose kingdom is an everlasting kingdom, and all dominions shall serve and obey him.
>   -- Daniel 7:26-27 (KJV)

"the judgment shall sit", i.e. that dominion be taken from the horn who made war with the saints, and be given to the saints. Dominion (שָׁלְטָן [Strong's H7985](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/Lexicon/Lexicon.cfm?strongs=H7985&t=KJV) - sholtan (Aramaic)) concerns sovereignty -- the responsibility of government, which means judgment of "*the kingdom under the whole heaven*" will be committed to the saints.

Comment: Thanks. You might want to answer my question about judging angels as well!

Answer (score 0):

There is a Judgment going on now in heaven.  God, the Father,  is the presiding Judge in this text.

The saints are all the righteous people of all ages. It is a Judgment not to eliminate people from God's coming Kingdom,  but to include all those who cling to the Lord and  Saviour.

So,  the good news about this Judgement is that all who cling to the Saviour will have a victory over sin.
Satan, and over death!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi Pastor Samuel Money. Welcome to the site! It looks like to you put a comment in an answer box. It would be interesting to hear your biblical answer to what you feel is an important question.

Comment: Welcome to Bible Hermeneutics! I edited your answer so it fits more with how we do answers here. Thanks for contributing and learning with us all!